# javascript export object to csv as a table

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv

I have a JS object (called df) that contains a number of arrays like so:

```
0: Array(2)
  0: "1405"
  1: "text string 1 #something"
1: Array(2)
  0: "1366"
  1: "text string 2 #hashtag"
603: Array(2)
  0: "92"
  1: "text string 603"
```

I want to export this into a csv file like so:

| Views | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1405 | text string 1 #something |
| 1366 | text string 2 #hashtag |
| 92 | text string 603 |

I can export to csv with this:

```
const blob = new Blob([df], { type: "text/csv; charset=utf-8;" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", url);
link.setAttribute("download", "export.csv");

document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

but the output is messy:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1405 | text string 1 |  |
| #something |  |  |
|  | 1366 | text string 2 #hasthag |

How can I clean this up in JS?

Edit:
I have since found the cause of the issue being line breaks in the text field resulting in the remaining text being pushed to a new line.

The solution was to use regex to remove line breaks at the point of extracting the text:

```
innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ")
```

Comment: conosle.log(`df`, df)

Comment: Try to create a minimal runnable demo project, such as on `codepen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You just need to convert the object to a `CSV` format string

```js
const autoDonwload = (obj) => {
  let result = `Views, Title`;
  for(const key in obj) {
    const [num, str] = obj[key];
    result += `\n`;
    result += `${num}, ${str}`;
  }
  // console.log(`result =\n`, result);
  const blob = new Blob([result], { type: "text/csv; charset=utf-8;" });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", url);
  link.setAttribute("download", "export.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
};

const obj = {
  0: ["1405", "text string 1 #something"],
  1: ["1366",  "text string 2 #hashtag"],
  603: ["92", "text string 603"],
};

autoDonwload(obj);
```

##### demo

[image]

> live demo

https://codepen.io/xgqfrms/pen/xxmodaB

##### update

> fix string contains `,` symbol issue

```js
const autoDonwload = (obj) => {
  // use `;` instead of `,` ✅
  let result = `Views; Title`;
  for(const key in obj) {
    const [num, str] = obj[key];
    result += `\n`;
    result += `${num}; ${str}`;
  }
  const blob = new Blob([result], { type: "text/csv; charset=utf-8;" });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", url);
  link.setAttribute("download", "export.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
};

const obj = {
  // string contains `,` symbol ❓
  0: ["1405", "text, string 1, #something"],
  1: ["1366",  "text string 2 #hashtag"],
  603: ["92", "text string 603"],
};

autoDonwload(obj);
```

[image]

##### refs

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: this works fantastic! thank you. the only issue i have is that when the text contains a comma it puts the rest of the text in a third, fourth, fifth column

Comment: I have updated my answer, it fixed your issue.